# cant perform shuffle hash join in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The last time I used spark when it was still V 1.4. Now I'm using 3.2, and am very eager to learn the performance of different kind of join in Spark. I cant seem to run a shuffle hash join in pyspark.

I run this code to disable shuffle sort join:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", "false")
```

and run my join statement:

```
df = small_table.join(big_table, small_table['id']==big_table['id'])
```

When I run

```
df.explain()
```

It keep on saying SortMergeJoin as the plan. It does change to broadcast if I use broadcast hash join. How can I enable shuffle hash join?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly pass join hint as below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", "false")

df = big_table.join(small_table.hint("SHUFFLE_HASH"), small_table['id']==big_table['id'])
```